# Passing JavaScript Parameters via Calling URL

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file that embeds a widget on a website. I want to be able to call this widget using a URL of the form:

```
http://domain.com/widget.js?variable=test
```

Within the JS script I want to be able to read in the value of the URL parameter 'variable' which is this case is 'test' and use it in the HTML code the JS outputs. I tried using window.location but that is returning the URL of the main webpage and not the URL that is being called to load the script.

Any ideas what the JS code looks like to read in a passed parameter? Thanks in advance!

Comment: does `document.location.search` or `parent.document.URL` help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through all `<script>` elements using `getElementsByTagName`.  Find the one which identifies your script (e.g. by looking for `domain.com/widget.js`) by examining the `src` attribute.  Extract the query string from the `src` attribute.

Example:

```
function getScriptQuery(identifier) {
 var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
     i, curScript;

 for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
  curScript = scripts[i];

  if (curScript.src.match(identifier)) {
   return (curScript.src.match(/\?.*/) || [undefined])[0];
  }
 }
}

alert(getScriptQuery('widget.js'));
```

---

There are two common alternatives to solving your original problem of passing data to the script.

You can reference a known global variable in your script and have the calling HTML define that variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var MyWidgetData={foo:'bar'};</script>
<script src="http://my.widgeteer.net/widget.js"></script>

// widget.js:

alert(MyWidgetData.foo);
```

You can also wrap your script as a named function and have calling HTML call that function:

```
<script src="http://my.widgeteer.net/widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">MyWidget({foo:'bar'});</script>

// widget.js:

function MyWidget(data) {
    alert(data.foo);
}
```

Comment: Is that really the easiest way to do this? JavaScript has to have some more efficient way to read the URL that called it. I guess not. If this is the easiest way, I'm not sure what would look like? Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: Quick follow up. Is there a better way to pass the parameters instead of the calling URL? Maybe adding them inside a script tag?

Comment: @Russell C., Added an example.  Anything inside the `<script>` tags won't be executed if the script specified in the `src` executes.  Similarly, if the `src` script fails to load, the contents of the `<script>` element executes.  Alternatives to passing arguments in the URL are passing arguments before the script is included (using a global variable) and wrapping your code in a function and having the user call that function with the parameters (preferably a parameter object).

Comment: Alternatively, you may consider server-side script generation

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - the whole point to why we are doing this is so we can serve static JS files so that won't work for us but good suggestion.

Comment: @Stager - Thanks for the example! Quick question about your last point. The whole thing we are trying to accomplish is to allow people to embed our widget in their website and then have that widget rendered. One thing we need in order to make that happen is to pass 1 or 2 variables to the static JS file which it needs to render correctly. Would your last point help enable that, and if so, is there some example code I could take a look at? Thanks again!

Comment: @Russell C., I have added examples to my two alternatives.  I hope this clears things up.

Comment: @Stager - Thanks that fixed the issue and is much more elegant than parsing the HTML of the page to find the URL. All your help is greatly appreciated!